# Why is only one card flipping?

Tags: javascript

I don't understand why the first card is flipping but the second is not. All I did was duplicate the html. Thanks for the help. I am new to javascript. It works on the first card but not on the second.

```
<div class="flipCard"> 
  <div class="card"> 
    <div class="side front"><img src="img/back100.png"></div> 
    <div class="side back"><img src="img/lion.png"></div> 
  </div> 
</div>

<div class="flipCard"> 
  <div class="card"> 
    <div class="side front"><img src="img/back100.png"></div> 
    <div class="side back"><img src="img/lion.png"></div> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

css

```
 .flipCard {
      -webkit-perspective: 800;
      -ms-perspective: 800;
      -moz-perspective: 800;
      -o-perspective: 800;
       width: 100px;
       height: 100px;
       position: relative;
    }
    .flipCard .card.flipped {
      transform:rotatey(-180deg);
    }
    .flipCard .card {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
      -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
      -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
      -moz-transition: 0.5s;
      -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
      -ms-transition: 0.5s;
      -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
      -o-transition: 0.5s;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
      transition: 0.5s;
    }
    .flipCard .card .side {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      cursor: pointer;
      position: absolute;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      z-index: 2;
      backface-visibility: hidden;  /* W3C */
      box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    }
    .flipCard .card .back {

      transform:rotatey(-180deg);

    }
```

JS

```
var cardToFlip = document.querySelector(".card");
cardToFlip.addEventListener("click", toggleToFlip);

function toggleToFlip() {
    this.classList.toggle("flipped");
}
```

EDIT: Here was the fix!!

```
var cardToFlip = document.querySelectorAll(".card");

    for (var card of cardToFlip){
    card.addEventListener("click", toggleToFlip);
    }

function toggleToFlip() {
    this.classList.toggle("flipped");
}
```

It's making me write more random words to submit this. Here are more random words.

Answer (score 6):

`document.querySelector(".card")` only selects the first match. Use `document.querySelectorAll(".card");` and then forEach over those:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".card").forEach( card => card.addEventListener('click', toggleToFlip) );
```

Comment: Thank you this worked!! I used a for-of instead because it seemed simpler but same idea!! 
 ``var cardToFlip = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
    
    for (var card of cardToFlip){
    card.addEventListener("click", toggleToFlip);
    }

function toggleToFlip() {
    this.classList.toggle("flipped");
}``